# simulate keypress on keypress

Tags: c, keyboard, x11, xcb

I'm trying to globally (not on a specific app window) listen out for a key's press/release and simulate another key, suppressing the original.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#include <xcb/xcb.h>  // requires -lxcb
#include <xcb/xtest.h>  // requires -lxcb-test

void sim_key_press(xcb_connection_t *xcon, xcb_keycode_t kc) {
    xcb_test_fake_input(xcon, XCB_KEY_PRESS, kc, XCB_CURRENT_TIME, XCB_NONE, 0, 0, 0);
    xcb_flush(xcon);
}

void sim_key_release(xcb_connection_t *xcon, xcb_keycode_t kc) {
    xcb_test_fake_input(xcon, XCB_KEY_RELEASE, kc, XCB_CURRENT_TIME, XCB_NONE, 0, 0, 0);
    xcb_flush(xcon);
}

int main() {
    const xcb_keycode_t GRAB_KEY = 65;
    const xcb_keycode_t SIM_KEY = 38;

    xcb_connection_t *xcon = xcb_connect(NULL, NULL);
    xcb_screen_t *xscreen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator(xcb_get_setup(xcon)).data;

    xcb_grab_key(xcon, 1, xscreen->root, XCB_NONE, GRAB_KEY, XCB_GRAB_MODE_ASYNC, XCB_GRAB_MODE_ASYNC);

    xcb_flush(xcon);

    xcb_generic_event_t *event;
    while ( (event = xcb_wait_for_event(xcon)) ) {
        switch (event->response_type & ~0x80) {
            case XCB_KEY_PRESS: {
                xcb_keycode_t kc = ((xcb_key_press_event_t *)event)->detail;
                printf("key press: %u\n", kc);  // debug
                sim_key_press(xcon, SIM_KEY);
                break;
            }
            case XCB_KEY_RELEASE: {
                xcb_keycode_t kc = ((xcb_key_release_event_t *)event)->detail;
                printf("key release: %u\n", kc);  // debug
                sim_key_release(xcon, SIM_KEY);
                break;
            }
        }
        free(event);
    }
}
```

Build with:

```
gcc -lxcb -lxcb-xtest c.c
```

The code above isn't working consistently at all. It is also detecting the simulated key even though it is not grabbed.

My end goal will also involve keys simulating potentially grabbed keys.

Is this the right approach? Is my end goal possible (could my program ignore it's own simulated keys)?